# 'bundle exec passenger start' failing on Rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger

I'm using passenger 5.3.2 in a Ruby on Rails app. My dev environment is MacOS 12.1, I'm using Ruby 2.6.6

Bundle install succeeded.

When I try and run
`bundle exec passenger start`
I get the following message:

```
 --> Downloading a Phusion Passenger agent binary for your platform
     Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.2/agent-x86_64-macosx-12.1.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404
     Trying next mirror...
     Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.2/agent-x86_64-macosx-12.1.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403
     ------------------------------------------
     Sorry, no precompiled agent binary is available for your platform.

---------------------------------------

The Phusion Passenger agent binary could not be downloaded. Compiling it from source instead.
```

It then proceeds

```
Checking for required software...

 * Checking for C compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/cc
 * Checking for C++ compiler...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/bin/c++
 * Checking for Rake (associated with /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/wrappers/ruby)...
      Found: yes
      Location: /Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/wrappers/rake
 * Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
      Found: yes
      curl-config location: /usr/bin/curl-config
      Header location: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/curl/curl.h
      Version: libcurl 7.77.0
      Usable: yes
      Supports SSL: yes
 * Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h
 * Checking for Zlib development headers...
      Found: yes
      Location: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h


--------------------------------------------

Compile the agent with optimizations?

Compiling the agent with optimizations will make Phusion Passenger faster, but
it will take longer to compile and it requires at least 2 GB of memory.

Compile with optimizations? [y/n]: n
```

After that it fails with error

```
*** ERROR: a Rake command failed. You can find the full log in /var/folders/9s/0sjkwffd4kv3xp_1y_xfcg8h0000gn/T/passenger-install-log-9wh8h1. Below, you can find the last few lines of the command's output.
------------- Begin command output snippet -------------
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c++ -o /var/folders/9s/0sjkwffd4kv3xp_1y_xfcg8h0000gn/T/passenger-install.2eduk2/support-binaries/WatchdogMain.o  -Isrc/agent -Isrc/cxx_supportlib -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy/libuv/include -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy/websocketpp -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-ambiguous-member-template -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -g -fno-limit-debug-info -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -c src/agent/Watchdog/WatchdogMain.cpp]
/Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-5.3.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:53:in `run_compiler'
/Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-5.3.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:104:in `compile_cxx'
/Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-5.3.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:162:in `block in define_cxx_object_compilation_task'
/Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
```

Any advice on how to resolve this?
I'm out of my depth here. Running with optimizations gives same result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.2/agent-x86_64-macosx-12.1.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404

If you visit the 5.3.2 index (https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.2/) you can see that the highest available MacOS version is 10.15.

> My dev environment is MacOS 12.1 ..

You can either downgrade your version of MacOS, or you can upgrade Passenger.

Comment: Thanks @jared-beck, that's helpful. However it's also a dead end since I am not looking to upgrade Passenger, I'm only trying to get my existing and previously functioning dev environment up and running again after buying a new laptop...

Any idea if Phusion has plans to support Monterey? I noticed other Passenger releases work on MacOS 11.

Comment: Ok, further checks suggest that Passenger 6.0.13 supports MacOS 12 (and 13 and 14...). Maybe that's my way out. Will have a try that soon.

Comment: I was never able to find a fix for this so I added puma to the GEM file and I start rails with `rails s puma`. It works fine for me. Hope this can help someone having this issue. I am on `MacOs 12 Monterey m1`